# How to do continuous deployment of ad django app from travis-ci

Tags: django, continuous-integration, travis-ci, continuous-deployment

I have this travis config:

```
language: python

services:
  - postgresql

python:
  - "2.7"
  - "2.6"

env:
  - DJANGO="django==1.6.2"

branches:
  only:
    - master

# command to install requirements
install:
  - pip install $DJANGO
  - pip install -r requirements.txt --use-mirrors
  - pip install -r networking_requirements.txt --use-mirrors
  - pip install coverage coveralls --use-mirrors
  - python setup.py install

before_script:
  - psql template1 -c 'CREATE EXTENSION hstore;'
  - psql -U postgres -c 'CREATE DATABASE nodeshot_travis;'
  - psql -U postgres -d nodeshot_travis -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"
  - psql -U postgres -d nodeshot_travis -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;"
  - cd tests
  - python manage.py syncdb --noinput
  - python manage.py migrate --noinput
  - python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 &

# command to run tests, e.g. python setup.py test
script:
  - coverage run --source=nodeshot runtests.py

after_success:
  coveralls
```

And after success I'd like to upgrade existing test servers (one or more).

I haven't well understood how. What is the most common way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way to do this is via [travis-ci deployments](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/), but the catch is that your provider has to be supported.

`after_success` is another option if your provider isn't supported by travis-ci. The disadvantage to this is that `after_success` will run on every build of your build matrix, so you have to worry about triggering multiple deployments with one build.

Comment: what if I want to push to a dedicated server or VPS? are there existing open source solutions that ease this?

Comment: You could use something like [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com) and call the deployment command on the Travis worker.